# Using formula in Crystal Report with empty data

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I'm new at Crystal report.

I have 2 column in different table like this:

```
banyak    peminjaman_banyak      
  2               1                 
  3               1          
  3               2          
  4
```

when i enter this code :

```
tonumber({list_komponen1.banyak})-tonumber(sum({peminjaman_alat1.peminjaman_banyak},{list_komponen1.nama_komponen}))
```

i get the result like this :

```
banyak    peminjaman_banyak     Total     
  2               1           1   
  3               1           2
  3               2           1
```

I want to show data like this:

```
banyak    peminjaman_banyak     Total     
  2               1               1
  3               1               2
  3               2               5
  4                               4
```

how can i subtract these table, when one off them doesn't have any value?
I hope you can understand what i mean.

Comment: Please provide more what you want to do, `{list_komponen1.nama_komponen}`?

Comment: @ArsalanKhan the record will be sort and grouped by `{list_komponen1.nama_komponen}`. list_komponen1 is table for banyak, peminjaman_alat for peminjaman_banyak

Comment: As I understand you simply do `{list_komponen1.banyak} - {peminjaman_alat1.peminjaman_banyak}` and then grouped and sort by `{list_komponen1.nama_komponen}`? is that you want

Comment: yeah, but, when `peminjaman_banyak` is null, they don't show anything except `peminjaman_banyak` not null